# How to extract some text from a url in Python

Tags: python, parsing, url, hyperlink

Im trying to have python extract some text out of URL string.

Here's example of URL https://somewebsite/images/products/SkuName/genricFileName.jpg

The SkuName always will come after the 5th "/" and will end by the 6th "/"

I would like to extract 'SkuName'

```
import urllib.request

images = input('please enter url list separated by ","')
names = input('please enter images names separated by ","')

images = images.split(',')
names =  names.split(',')

for index, image in enumerate(images):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, "images/{}.jpg".format(names[index])) 
print('images downloaded successfully')
```

As you can see, the user have to manually enter the SKU Name (which goes under variable 'names')

I would like the user to enter only one input (URL) and python automatically extract the SKUName out of the URL string

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the (absolute) position of the name in the URL won't change, then `url.split('/')[5]` should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implamnt that in mycode.. 

for index, image in enumerate(images):
          
          urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, "temp/{}.jpg".format(image.split('/')[:-2]))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using python regex. 
Note: change the pattern as per your url

```
import re
url = 'https://somewebsite/images/products/SkuName/genricFileName.jpg'
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=(https://somewebsite/images/products/)).*(?=/genricFileName.jpg)', re.I)
sku_name = pattern.search(url).group()
```

Answer (score 0):

If that format is fix you can just split the url and access the second last element from the resulting list:

```py
url = "https://somewebsite/images/products/SkuName/genricFileName.jpg"
skuName = url.split("/")[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be aware of the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function already. You can use that, in combination with [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to get you what you need.

```
skuName = input('url').split('/')[:-2]
```

This will yield the second to last element in the list. You could also search for the the 6th element by using.

```
skuName = input('url').split('/')[5]
```